# Regex to exclude words followed by space

Tags: python, regex

I tried a lot of solutions but can't get this Regex to work.

The string-
"Flow Control          None"

I want to exclude "Flow Control" plus the blank space, and only return whatever is on the right.

Comment: Just match on `Flow Control (.+)` then extract only the capturing group.

Comment: You can also use `str.replace` or `str.index` depending on your situation.

Comment: Can you include more sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged your question with `#python` and `#regex`, I'll outline a simple solution to your problem using these tools. Furthermore, the other two answers don't really tackle the exact problem of matching *"whatever is on the right"* of your `"Flow Control "` prefix.

1. First, start by importing the `re` builtin module ([read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)).

```py
import re
```

2. Define the pattern you want to match. Here, we're matching *"whatever is on the right"* (`(?P<suffix>.+)$`) of `^Flow Control` .

```py
pattern = re.compile(r"^Flow Control (?P<suffix>.+)$")
```

3. Grab the match for a given string (e.g. `"Flow Control None"`)

```py
suffix = pattern.search("Flow Control None").group("suffix")
print(suffix)  # Out: None
```

---

Hopefully, this complete working example will also help you

```py
import re


def get_suffix(text: str):
    pattern = re.compile(r"^Flow Control (?P<suffix>.+)$")
    matches = pattern.search(text)
    return matches.group("suffix") if matches else None


examples = [
    "Flow Control None",
    "Flow Control None None",
    "Flow Control  None",
    "Flow Control ",
]

for example in examples:
    suffix = get_suffix(text=example)
    if suffix:
        print(f"Matched: {repr(suffix)}")
    else:
        print(f"No matches for: {repr(example)}")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked great. I ended up using the simpler regex solution posted below but if it didn't work for any outliers, your solution, although a little longer is the way to go. I added the following to make it remove quotation marks and space. `xt = f"{repr(right)}"` `xt = xt.strip('\' ')` `xt.strip()` `print(xt)`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a purely regex solution try this: `(?<= )[a-zA-Z]*$`

The `(?<= )` matches a single ' ' but doesn't include it in the match. `[a-zA-Z]*` matches anything from a to z or A to Z any number of times. `$` matches the end of the line.

You could also try replacing the `*` with a `+` if you want to ensure that your match has at least one letter (`*` will produce a 0-length match if your string ends in a space, `+` will match nothing).

But it may be clearer to do something like

```
data = "Flow Control None"
split = data.split(' ')
split[len(split) - 1] # returns "None"
```

**EDIT** `data.split(' ')[-1]` also returns `"None"`
or

```
data[data.rfind(' ') + 1:] # returns "None"
```

that don't involve regexes at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` like so:

```
my_str = 'Flow Control None'
out_str = my_str.split()[-1]
# 'None'
```

Or use `re.findall`:

```
import re
out_str = re.findall(r'^.*\s(\S+)$', my_str)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you Timur, it worked perfectly. Both these options are good, thanks for your time.